# CSS/JS Resize/Crop images in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have another question. I'm using HTML KickStart, without PhP and anything. Pure css/js.
There are gallery's with images. Every image have usual code like

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="image.jpg"><img src="image_small.jpg" width="160" height="160"></a>
</div>
```

with effects and stuff. Question is - HOW TO dynamicly crop/resize thumbs to display them? Idea is to make something like this

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="image.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

using SAME image but i dont have to crop/resize each one in photoshop, yea, there are options like "Dropresize" where i can make them small in a few minutes, but still, it's more usefull when you can use 1 image (and automaticly get resized thumb) than 2 different ones.

Images can be any size, up to 900px width (or height, or both) so thumb must be
1) Resized to 160px on shortest side (160x210, or 300x160, any orientation)
2) Longest side has to be cropped, or must have specific margin values

Any options?

Comment: You should use <canvas> for this, specifically the `drawImage` method as described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#section_7

Comment: I dont think canvas is an option because it's a problem for IE (up to 9 version) and some old firefoxes, and opera. In other hand CSS/JS is always working, so i'm trying not to use CANVAS if it's not necessary

Comment: OK, in that case look into the CSS `clip` property. You'll still need to do some maths in order to determine the clip values, but you can arrive at the same result without using canvas. There's a good example at http://www.seifi.org/css/creating-thumbnails-using-the-css-clip-property.html

Comment: Seems nice, but there are RECT pixels value, so it's ... idk, because there is no <img onLoad=getPixels(this.style.width, this.style.height)> ... property or something. But clip is a nice thing. More ideas?

Comment: Are you actually wanting to save a copy of the cropped image, rather than just display in-browser? If so canvas or Flash are your options.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a number of **CSS** classes like so:

```
.thumb {
    max-width: 900px; 
}

.thumb160px {
    width: 160px; 
    height: 210px;
}

.thumb300px {
    width: 300px; 
    height: 160px;
}
```

OR, set just one value such as the width, like so:

```
.thumb160px {
    width: 160px; 
    height: auto;
}

.thumb300px {
    max-width: 300px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

And apply this to your **HTML** elements, like so:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="image.jpg"><img class="thumb300px" src="image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```